# List to EntityCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entitycollection

I've been trying to add some selected items from a multi-select listbox on my entry class.

After some research I found that this solution would work:

```
EntityCollection<Publisher> entityCollection = new EntityCollection<Publisher>();

foreach (Publisher pub in this.publishersLst.SelectedItems)
{
    entityCollection.Attach(pub);
}
```

but even though it solved the first problem I was having I'm getting a new one now. One that I can't seem to find the solution... I even tried detaching the entity, but with no luck.

The error I get now is:

> Requested operation is not allowed when the owner of this RelatedEnd is null. RelatedEnd objects that were created with the default constructor should only be used as a container during serialization.

have anyone been through this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it a different way.

```
            entry.Publishers = new EntityCollection<Publisher>();

            foreach (Publisher item in this.publishersLst.SelectedItems)
            {
                entry.Publishers.Add(item);
            }
```

Needed a new List to work.

Regards.